# Check if React component contains styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I have the following component which uses styled-components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ColumnTitle = styled.h3`
  color: green;
`;

const column = (props) => {
  return (
    <ColumnTitle>{props.title}</ColumnTitle>
  )
};
```

I am trying to test (using enzyme / jest) that the `column` component renders an `h3` which contains the specified text (I am not trying to test any styles, I just want to know that it is being rendered):

```
test('column contains h3 with correct text', () => {
  const column = shallow(
    <Column title={'heading'} />
  );
  const ColumnTitle = styled.h3`color: green;`;
  expect(column.contains(<ColumnTitle>heading</ColumnTitle>)).toEqual(true);
});
```

I've tried several variations but the test always fails. If I simply test that the column contains the word `heading` then it passes, ie:

```
expect(column.contains('heading')).toEqual(true);
```

But I want to test that the column contains an `h3` element which in turn contains the correct text. This is what I get if I `console.log(column.debug())`:

```
<styled.h3>
  heading
</styled.h3>
```

I have tried the following which also fails:

```
expect(column.contains(<styled.h3>heading</styled.h3>)).toEqual(true);
```

Any suggestions?